# Multiple return type showing error in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have an Angular service. The method of that service calls an API and return an object. Now I would like to modify that service function. I want that if the API call returns object then the function will return the object as observable but the API returns null then the function will return a string of message. Here is my angular Code:

```
getAccountDetailsById(id: number): Observable<AccountInfo> | string {
        return this.service.get<AccountResultInfo>(`${this.apiPATH}accountById/${id}`)
            .pipe(map(user => {
                if (user.Account) {
                    return user.Account;
                } else {
                    return user.Message;
                }
            }));
    }
```

But it shows below error:

> Type 'Observable<string | AccountInfo>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.
> Type 'string | AccountInfo' is not assignable to type 'AccountInfo'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AccountInfo'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your return type is wrong/typoed. Should be:

```js
getAccountDetailsById(id: number): Observable<AccountInfo | string>
```

Comment: After calling the method how can I convert the return type in my angular component? How would I know which thing is returned from service?

Comment: You can't. What you could do is to type check the result in the place your need the type --e.g: `if(typeof res === 'string')`.